# API cannot be defined if there are two create tasks in two different controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-7.0

I have two controllerbases and the tasks are almost the same but when I have the same create method the error occurs:

[image]

Here is the code in my program.cs class:

```cs
using DATA;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using SERVICE.FuncCategory;
using SERVICE.FuncCustomer;
using System.Reflection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//add service
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, Categorieservice>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
//swagger
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "ToDo API",
        Description = "An ASP.NET Core Web API for managing ToDo items",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "Example Contact",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/contact")
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Example License",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
        }
    });
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(options =>
    {
        options.SerializeAsV2 = true;
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

here is the code in category controller class

```
using ENTITY;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SERVER.Models.CategoryModel;
using SERVICE.FuncCategory;

namespace SERVER.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CategoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
        public CategoryController(ICategoryService categoryService)
        {
            _categoryService = categoryService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var CategoryIndex = _categoryService.GetCategories().Select(index => new Indexs
            {
                CategoryName = index.CategoryName,
            });
            return Ok(CategoryIndex);
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            if (id.Equals(0))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var ResultId = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(id);
            if (ResultId == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var CategoryDetail = new Details
            {
                CategoryId = ResultId.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = ResultId.CategoryName,
                Description = ResultId.Description
            };
            return Ok(CategoryDetail);
        }
        [HttpGet("{name}")]
        public IActionResult FindByName(string name)
        {
            var ResultName = _categoryService.GetCategoryByName(name);
            if (ResultName == null)
                return BadRequest(ResultName);
            var CategoryDetail = new Details
            {
                CategoryId = ResultName.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = ResultName.CategoryName,
                Description = ResultName.Description
            };
            return Ok(CategoryDetail);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Creates creates)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if (creates == null)
                return BadRequest();
            var CheckExist = await _categoryService.CheckCategoryExistById(creates.CategoryId);
            if (CheckExist)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var CategoryCreate = new Category
            {
                CategoryId = creates.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = creates.CategoryName,
                Description = creates.Description
            };
            await _categoryService.CreateCategoryAsync(CategoryCreate);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Detail), new { id = CategoryCreate.CategoryId }, CategoryCreate);
        }
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, Updates updates)
        {
            if (id == 0) return BadRequest();
            if (updates == null)
                return BadRequest();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var CheckExits = await _categoryService.CheckCategoryExistById(updates.CategoryId);
            if (!CheckExits)
                return BadRequest();
            var CategoryUpdate = new Category
            {
                CategoryId = updates.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = updates.CategoryName,
                Description = updates.Description
            };
            await _categoryService.UpdateCategoryAsync(CategoryUpdate);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Detail), new { id = CategoryUpdate.CategoryId }, CategoryUpdate);
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            if (id == 0) return BadRequest();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var CheckExist = await _categoryService.CheckCategoryExistById(id);
            if (!CheckExist)
                return BadRequest();
            var CategoryDelete = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(id);
            if (CategoryDelete != null)
                return BadRequest(CategoryDelete);
            await _categoryService.DeleteCategoryAsync(CategoryDelete);
            return NoContent();
        }

    }
}
```

here is the code in customer controller code

```
using ENTITY;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SERVER.Models.CustomesModel;
using SERVICE.FuncCustomer;

namespace SERVER.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;
        public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
        {
            _customerService = customerService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var CustomerIndex = _customerService.GetAllCustoms().Select(index => new Indexs
            {
                FullName = index.FullName,
            }).ToList();
            return Ok(CustomerIndex);
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return BadRequest();
            var ResultId = _customerService.GetCustomerById(id);
            if (ResultId == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();

            }
            var CustomerDetail = new Details
            {
                CustomerId = ResultId.CustomerId,
                FullName = ResultId.FullName,
                Email = ResultId.Email
            };
            return Ok(CustomerDetail);
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return BadRequest();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var CheckExist = await _customerService.CheckCustomersExistById(id);
            if (!CheckExist) return BadRequest(CheckExist);
            var CustomerDelete = _customerService.GetCustomerById(id);
            if (CustomerDelete == null)
                return NotFound();
            await _customerService.DeleteCustomerAsync(CustomerDelete);
            return NoContent();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Creates creates)
        {
            return Ok(creates);
        }
    }
}
```

If I delete task create in customer controller class, it will run as image below:

[image]

I want to run or test many API at the time.

Comment: There are several issues with this question that should be addressed: 1. Please show the images instead of linking to them, but as a general rule, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); paste in the text. 2. There's a lot of code, and it's unlikely that anyone is going to read through all of it. Please supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try delete this one `options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` I tested your code works well without this line.

Comment: it's still not working